# regex to match passwords that are greater than 5 characters long and have two consecutive digits

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's what I have, can someone please tell me where I am wrong?

```js
let sampleWord = "bana12";
let pwRegex = /(?=\w{5})(?=\d{2,})/; // Change this line
let result = pwRegex.test(sampleWord);
console.log(result);
```

It works for passwords that contain only letters or only numbers, but not for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.*` before `\d{2}` since the consecutive digits may occur anywhere in the string. Your current regex should check for two digits to be present at very first.

```js
let sampleWord = "bana12";
let pwRegex = /^(?=\w{5})(?=.*\d{2,})/; // Change this line
console.log( pwRegex.test(sampleWord))
```

Note that `\w` matches only the word characters, so your regex fails if there input string contain 5 non-word characters. So for checking the string length, it's better to use `.` instead of `\w`.

```
let pwRegex = /^(?=.{5})(?=.*\d{2,})/;
```

Comment: for 5 word chars anywhere at the string `let pwRegex = /^(?=.*\w{5})(?=.*\d{2,})/`